Difference between the Schauder estimate (of divergence form) proven by Leon Simon and Caccioppoli
I recently read two ways to prove Schauder estimate.
One is from Leon Simon ,his main method mainly depends on a key lemma, and the way to prove the key lemma is rescale and blow-up. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.01564 in Section 2.4.The theorem is stated as follows:
Theorem 2.28 (Schauder estimates in divergence form). Let $u\in C^{1, \alpha }$ $be$
$\text{a weak solution to}$
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n\partial_i\big(a_{ij}(x)\partial_ju(x)\big)=f(x)\quad in\quad B_1,$$
with $f\in L^q( B_1) \text{ for }q\geq \frac n{1- \alpha }, \text{ and }a_{ij}( x) \in C^{0, \alpha }( B_1) \text{ for some }\alpha \in ( 0, 1)$,
such that $( a_{ij}( x) ) _{ij}$ fulflls the ellipticity condition
$$0<\lambda\operatorname{Id}\leq(a_{ij}(x))_{ij}\leq\Lambda\operatorname{Id}\quad in\quad B_1,$$
$\text{for some 0}< \lambda \leq \Lambda < \infty . \text{ Then, }$
$$\|u\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(B_{1/2})}\leq C\left(\|u\|_{L^\infty(B_1)}+\|f\|_{L^q(B_1)}\right)$$
$\text{for some constant C depending only on }\alpha , n, \lambda , \Lambda , \text{ and }\| a_{ij}\| _{C^{0, \alpha }( B_{1}) }.$
The other is from Han Lin's book Elliptic Partial Differential Equations. This proof is from Cacciopolli.The theorem is stated as follows(broken into four theorems):
Consider $ (*)\quad \displaystyle\intop_{\boldsymbol{B}_1}a_{ij}D_iuD_j\varphi+cu\varphi=\intop_{\boldsymbol{B}_1}f\varphi\quad\text{for any }\varphi\in H_0^1(B_1).$
THEOREM 3.8 Let $u\in H^1( B_1) \text{ solve }( * ) . \text{ Assume a}_{ij}\in C^0( \bar{B} _1) , c\in L^n( B_1)$, and$\left.f\in L^q(B_1)\text{for some q}\in(\frac n2,n).\text{Then u}\in C^\alpha(B_1)\text{with }\alpha=2-\frac nq\in(0,1).\right.$ Moreover,there exists an $R_0=R_0(\lambda,\Lambda,\tau,\|c\|_{L^n})$ such that for any $x\in B_1/2$ and $r\leq R_0$ there holds
$$\int_{B_r(x)}|Du|^2\leq Cr^{n-2+2\alpha}\{\|f\|_{L^q(B_1)}^2+\|u\|_{H^1(B_1)}^2\}$$
where$C=C(\lambda,\Lambda,\tau,\|c\|_{L^n})$is a positive constant with
$$|a_{ij}(x)-a_{ij}(y)|\leq\tau(|x-y|)\quad for\text{ any }x,y\in B_1.$$
THEOREM 3.13 Let $u \in H^1(B_1)$ solve $(*)$. Assume $a_{ij} \in C^\alpha(\bar{B}_1)$, $c \in L^q(B_1)$, and $f \in L^q(B_1)$ for some $q > n$ and $\alpha = 1 - \frac{n}{q} \in (0, 1)$. Then $Du \in C^\alpha(B_1)$. Moreover, there exists an $R_0 = R_0(\lambda, |a_{ij}|_{C^\alpha}, |c|_{L^q})$ such that for any $x \in B_{1/2}$ and $r \leq R_0$, the following holds:
$$\int_{B_r(x)} |Du - (Du)_{x, r}|^2 \leq Cr^{n + 2\alpha} \{ \|f\|_{L^q(B_1)}^2 + \|u\|_{H^1(B_1)}^2 \},$$
where $C = C(\lambda, |a_{ij}|_{C^\alpha}, |c|_{L^q})$ is a positive constant.
THEOREM 3.1 Suppose $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ satisfies
$$\int_{B_r(x)} |u - u_{x, r}|^2 \leq M^2 r^{n + 2\alpha} \quad \text{for any } B_r(x) \subset \Omega$$
for some $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Then $u \in C^\alpha(\Omega)$, and for any $\Omega' \subset \subset \Omega$, there holds
$$\sup_{\Omega'} |u| + \sup_{\substack{x, y \in \Omega' \\ x \neq y}} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha} \leq c \{ M + \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \},$$
where $c = c(n, \alpha, \Omega, \Omega') > 0$.
Corollary 3.2. Suppose $u \in H_{\mathrm{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ satisfies  $ \int_{B_r(x)} |Du|^2 \leq M^2 r^{n-2+2\alpha}, $for any $ B_r(x) \subset \Omega, \, r \in (0,1).$  Then $u \in \mathbb{C}^\alpha(\Omega)$ and for any $\Omega^{\prime} \Subset \Omega$, there holds  $ \sup_{\Omega^{\prime}} |u| + \sup_{\substack{x,y \in \Omega^{\prime} \\ x \neq y}} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} \leq c \{ M + \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \},$
where $c = c(n, \alpha, \Omega, \Omega^{\prime}) > 0$.
Theorem 3.8 together with corollary 3.2, implies $u\in C^{\alpha}$, while theorem 3.13 toghther with theorem 3.1 implies $u\in C^{1,\alpha}$.This coincides with theorem 2.28,i.e. Schauder estimates in divergence form.
I'm fine with the proof presented in the books, but I'm interested in three questions:
1.I know that for non-divergence form , if $f\in C^{\alpha},a_{ij}\in C^{\alpha}$,then $u\in C^{2,\alpha}$, while in divergence form, we only get $f\in L^q,a_{ij}\in C^{\alpha}$ implies $u\in C^{1,\alpha}$. I wonder in divergence form, if we replace $f\in L^q$ with $f\in C^{\alpha}$, can we get the same result(i.e. $u\in C^{2,\alpha}$)?
2.I wonder between the two results above, which one is better? The only difference I discovered is Leon Simon asks  $q\geq \frac n{1- \alpha }$ and Caccioppoli asks $\alpha=2-\frac nq$. I think the latter condition is stronger than the previous one, hence the previous result is better,am I right?
3.The method from Cacciopolli seems not to include any functional analysis aurgument, this seems incredible since I would expect a "a priori estimate - functional analysis method" argument for the regularity of solutions. Are there any other proofs like this?

Q2. There is a major difference between the two approaches. Simon's proof is very elegant, but it is a proof by contradiction, so it needs to assume that you already know that your weak solution $u$ belongs to $C^{1,\alpha}$. This is a serious drawback since you usually use Sobolev spaces and the Lax-Milgram theorem (or similar) to prove the existence of weak solutions.
If you are working with the Poisson equation, $\Delta u=f$, then the easy way out is to mollify both $u$ and $f$.
For more general equations, you should approximate $f$ and $a_{ij}$ with a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions. Then you have to prove $C^\infty$ regularity for those (say, using Nirenberg difference quotients). Then, you apply Simon's theorem to the approximating solutions and pass to the limit.
A good reference on how to go from Schauder apriori estimates to the regularity of weak solutions is Grisvard's book "Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains." See Lemma 6.3.2.2
Cacciopoli's theorem has the advantage of starting with a weak solution in a Sobolev space and proving regularity, and Holder estimates it simultaneously.

Thanks for the answer, but it seems that the lecture notes are not available(it says”not found”). Could you please provide another one?

Q1: I doubt there is such a result, it is unreasonable to expect you get 2 regularity lifting from only a $C^0$ coefficient (whose derivative may be discontinuous). But if you are willing to assume $a_{ij}\in C^{1,\alpha}$, then the argument is pretty straightforward, expand the divergence operator, move to the term $\sum_{ij}\partial_i a_{ij} \partial_j u$ to the right hand side and apply the non-divergence form result.

Thanks for mentioning that, and I realized 2 things:
1: I should have cited two more theorems on Han-Lin's book, which have already been posted in the question now;
2: I have to consider the regularity of $f$  and $a_{ij}$ in the same time. Theorem 3.8 seems a different result: it only asks $a_{ij}$ to be $C^0$ to get $u\in C^\alpha$.  Now I have edited my question. But it seems that in both divergent and non-divergent cases we only need $a_{ij}\in C^{\alpha}$ rather than $C^{1,\alpha}$
